# How do I increment a value in a while loop in Python>?

Tags: python, while-loop, range

I'm trying to find the area of a space under a curve on a graph. This is being done by getting the area of multiple rectangles with a constant base but incrementing heights. The rectangles are between two endpoints given my the user. The incrementations are from point a and by 0.1 until it reaches point b. My question is, how do I increment the x in a while loop if I can't use a range? I tried using the += bit so x= a+=1 but that gives a syntax error.

```
print("Computing the area under the curve x^2 + x + 1")
a = int(input("Enter the left end point a: x ="))
b = int(input("Enter the left end point b: x ="))


base = 0.1
x = 0

while (a <= x <= b):
    area = (x**2 + x + 1) * base
    x += area
```

Comment: ` I tried using the += bit so x= a+=1 but that gives a syntax error.` needs to be a bit clearer. `x += area` *does* increment `x` in every loop, but I suspect that what you want is `x = x + base`, which is the increment you're moving each loop. The conditional is also wrong, you want `(a <= x) and (x <= b)`.

Comment: @NathanielFord Your `(a <= x) and (x <= b)` is equivalent to theirs.

Comment: @NathanielFord - `while a <= x <= b:` is a proper chained operation and does the same thing as `(a <= x) and (x <= b)`. OP: Loose those parens in the `while`, they are not needed.

Comment: Fair enough - I couldn't remember offhand if Python currently supported that.

Answer (score 0):

Try increment left end point variable `a` instead of defining and incrementing `x`.

```
print("Computing the area under the curve x^2 + x + 1")
a = int(input("Enter the left end point a: x = "))
b = int(input("Enter the right end point b: x = "))

base = 0.1
total_area = 0

while (a <= b):
    sub_area = (a**2 + a + 1) * base
    total_area += sub_area
    a += base
    
print("The area under the curve is " + str(total_area))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. x should be equal to a, because the range of x is from a to b.
2. In each loop, you have to let a add 0.1.
3. Set a new variable to record the total area, such as 'total_area' as follows.

```
    print("Computing the area under the curve x^2 + x + 1")
    a = int(input("Enter the left end point a: x ="))
    b = int(input("Enter the left end point b: x ="))
    
    
    base = 0.1
    x = a # 1
    total_area = 0
    
    while (a <= x <= b):
        area = (x**2 + x + 1) * base
        x += base # 2
        total_area += area # 3
    
    print(total_area)
```